# How can I get rid of the `''` and `()` chars?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm executing this code:

```
def filewrite():
    filew = open('company.dat', 'a')
    custid = str(input('Enter Customer ID:'))
    Widg = abs(float(input('Quantity of Widgets Ordered:')))
    Gidg = abs(float(input('Quantity of Gidgets Ordered:')))
    Dood = abs(float(input('Quantity of Doodads Ordered:')))
    widt = Widg * 10.55
    gidt = Gidg * 7.30
    doodt = Dood * 5.25
    total = widt + gidt + doodt
    wida = (Widg, 'Widgets Ordered @ $10.55', format(widt,',.2f'))
    gida = (Gidg, 'Gidgets Ordered @ $7.30', format(gidt,',.2f'))
    dooda = (Dood, 'Doodads Ordered @ $5.25', format(doodt,',.2f'))
    filew.write('\n')
    filew.write(custid + '\n')
    filew.write(str(wida))
    filew.write(str(gida))
    filew.write(str(dooda))
    filew.close()


def fileread():
    filer = open('company.dat', 'r')
    read = filer.read()
    filer.close()
    print(read, end='')

again = True

while again == True:
    print('1 - Add a new Invoice Order')
    print('2 - Display all Invoice Orders')
    print('3 - Quit')

    choice = abs(int(input('Enter 1, 2, or 3:')))

    if choice > 3:
        print('Error, no choice of such available.')
        choice = abs(int(input('Enter 1, 2, or 3:')))


    if choice == 1:
        filewrite()
        print('\n')

    if choice == 2:
        fileread()
        print('\n')

    if choice == 3:
        exit()
```

When I enter everything and read the file it comes out as:

```
As234
(12.0, 'Widgets Ordered @ $10.55', '126.60')(1.0, 'Gidgets Ordered @ $7.30', 
'7.30')(3.0, 'Doodads Ordered @ $5.25', '15.75')
```

How can I get rid of the `()` and `''` that displays?

I'm new to coding and taking a beginning python class, this is one of my assignment and I am stuck on this.

Comment: You get rid of them by not deliberately including them in the first place … after a `x = (1, "wot")`, the use of `str(x)` will return *exactly* that again.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is how you create your variables.
Here you create some variables as integers:

```
Widg = abs(float(input('Quantity of Widgets Ordered:')))
Gidg = abs(float(input('Quantity of Gidgets Ordered:')))
Dood = abs(float(input('Quantity of Doodads Ordered:')))
```

but then here you make a list using each variable:

```
wida = (Widg, 'Widgets Ordered @ $10.55', format(widt,',.2f'))
gida = (Gidg, 'Gidgets Ordered @ $7.30', format(gidt,',.2f'))
dooda = (Dood, 'Doodads Ordered @ $5.25', format(doodt,',.2f'))
```

which then when you cast into string `str(wida)` you get exactly what was printed, since that's what you provided for the cast.

You should check what kind of variables you want to create, and do one of the following:

1. Cast to print by formatting the items in your list
2. Create a class to hold the items you currently have in a list (wida, gida, dooda), where you can take each variable in the class separately.

If you have any problem with the second option, please comment or read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: This solution is far more robust. I'd avoid using mine.

Answer (score 0):

As @usr2564301 has said, the most simple way of achieving your goal would be to not them in the first place.

If you **must** (and I don't recommend it), you can replace characters in Python strings. It must be noted, stings are immutable, so you must create a new string to do this.

```
x = "(12.0, 'Widgets Ordered @ $10.55', '126.60')(1.0, 'Gidgets Ordered @ $7.30', '7.30')(3.0, 'Doodads Ordered @ $5.25', '15.75')"

a = x.replace("(", "")
b = a.replace(")", "")
c = b.replace("'", "")


print(c)
```

returns

`12.0, Widgets Ordered @ $10.55, 126.601.0, Gidgets Ordered @ $7.30, 7.303.0, Doodads Ordered @ $5.25, 15.75`

Comment: you are fixing his strings, but the problem here is HOW those variables were actually created, and not just fixing them

Comment: I agree. I'm going to leave it up for reference, though it's not necesarily on-topic for this question.